# How can I use ffmpeg to stream over http

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, streaming, vlc

I am using the follow commands to stream to my localhost

```
ffmpeg -i b.mp4 -r 60 -bufsize 1024k -vcode libtheora -qscale:v 1 -f ogg "udp://@127.0.0.1/video.ogg"

ffmpeg -i b.mp4 -r 60 -bufsize 1024k -vcode libtheora -qscale:v 1 -f ogg "http://127.0.0.1/video.ogg"
```

The both work very well, at least do not show any errors, but when I try play such http stream does not, it gave me error "not found"

Can somebody help me on it? I am complety lost in this issue...also when I try include some port, for example `ffmpeg -i b.mp4 -r 60 -bufsize 1024k -vcode libtheora -qscale:v 1 -f ogg "http://127.0.0.1:8980/video.ogg"` provide me input/output error...I have test the equivalent commands on vlc and is work as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to put a video available on the web, is:

**1 - Transcode the video with the ffmpeg.** Recommended with h264, why? Only PC browsers (except Opera) support it, is much more efficient h264 or VP8 (livpx). 
The call to ffmpeg should be:

*h264*

```
ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac out.mp4
```

*vp8*

```
ffmpeg -i input -vcodec libvpx -acodec vorbis out.webm
```

*Theora*

```
ffmpeg -i input -acodec vorbis -vcodec libtheroa out.ogg
```

**2 - Install a web server** like Apache or Nginx Lighttpd

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd
```

**3 - Link www folder** with the folder out with ffmpeg ln -ls

```
sudo ln -ls / var / www /   / home / your_user / path_to_out_ffmpeg
```

Your method is wrong because when you have stopped ffmpeg your contents aren't avaliable. It  method is only avaliable for live video.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply Cibran!! It help me a lot to understand, just something more is missing...my initial idea was provide playback from live stream, I means take tv channels, live cameras,....and put on localhost. Using your solution obligue to record continuosly but also never will provide something like "realtime" live stream, always will started from recorded movie beggining...Have you some idea regarding? Just I would like to avoid wowza, FMS,....